# Run automtion anywhere bot even when runners are in sleep mode

Tags: automation, automationanywhere, java-bridge-method

I'm facing issues in running bot on a runner in RDP , the runner runs the bot when i have logged on it remotely but when i disconnect remote access , the commands like active window, screen shot, cloning etc fails. I want to run the bot without having to remotely login the runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the resolution was the culprit. 1366x768 would give the best results in unattended automation.